# Extracting substring using Regex

Tags: regex

In an JSP file I have a value

```
path="roleObj.obj1"
```

With this I need to extract obj1 value.

I am successfully able to extract  roleObj.obj1  value using regex -

```
 path="(\w.*?)"
```

How do I need to change to get my target value?

Comment: `\.(\w+)(?=")` and $1 gives your what you are after.

Comment: @Wiktor done....thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
path="(\w+?\.(\w+?))"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ2uJ3/5)

You can retrieve "roleObj.obj1" from $1 and "obj1" from $2